# The following is a Taylor Series evaluated a particular value of x, find the sum of the series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

This is the Taylor Series in question
1 + $\frac{2}{1!}$+$\frac{4}{2!}$+$\frac{8}{3!}$+...+$\frac{2^n}{n!}$+...

I know how to find whether or not the series converges or diverges easily using the ratio test. I find that it converges. However, I don't know exactly how to find what value it converges to because the limit that you find using the ratio test doesn't yield the actual value that you converge to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, the ratio test does not give a value for the series. If you want a value for the series, take a look at the power series of $e^x$

Comment: Oh okay, so the sum is just e^2 then. I do have a similar question. If I know that 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + . . . = 5, I know I can just use the rules about a geometric series to solve for x, but is there some way to solve for x using ideas about Taylor Series?

Comment: Well you can notice that the power series of $1/(1-x)$ is $1+x+x^2+...$ and that when you solve for x you get $x=4/5<1$ so the power series converges. This is really just the rule about geometric series but formatted in a slightly different way

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$1+\frac{2}{1!}+\frac{4}{2!}+...+\frac{2^n}{n!}+...=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{2^n}{n!}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{n!}\right)^2=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{e^2\Gamma(m+1,2)}{\Gamma(m+1)}$$

Comment: I think introductory the gamma function might be a bit of overkill here

Comment: @ASKASK It was the way I got into this series, so I thought maybe it will help

Comment: You learned of the gamma function before you learned of the exponential power series?

Comment: @ASKASK I learned it in the same time!

Comment: Since you've introduced the gamma function, but most of us do not master it at the same time as the exponential power series, perhaps it is worth finishing off your answer, as many Readers many not benefit from this "hint".